# simple .htaccess rewrite issues

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am new with .htaccess and need a hand with a simple rewrite.

How can I change the following:

from

mysite.com/seattle

to

mysite.com/?city=seattle

I have tried the following with now luck:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ ?city=$1 [L]
```

Also, it would be ideal if the user still sees mysite.com/seattle.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?city=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Note that the destination filename (`index.php` in this case) is required, otherwise you'll get a 500 error.  Also note that I added `QSA` so that the query string is appended properly.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to go and test this. I was taught that in that particular case on vs On mattered in that directive and have just always done it/never thought to test to see if the other way worked. You learn something new every day.